# How to set one text in ComboBox items and get different value in javafx fxml

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, fxml

I want to set one combo box value like this

```
<ComboBox fx:id="dimensionCombo" editable="true" promptText="Other" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="13" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">

                  <String fx:value="30X20" />
                  <String fx:value="30X40" />
                  <String fx:value="30X50" />
                  <String fx:value="60X40" />

                </FXCollections>
</ComboBox>
```

But when I do `dimensionCombo.getValue()` , I should get a different value like `600` for `<String fx:value="30X20" />` , `1200` for `<String fx:value="30X40" />` and so on. Is this possible? if yes how?

Now i'm doing (In Controller)

```
...

if(dimensionCombo.getValue().equals("30X20")) {
    int value = 600;
}
else if(dimensionCombo.getValue().equals("30X40")) {
    int value = 1200;
}

...
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to define the Collection to be used by the combobox in the FXML?

Comment: I want some default values when the page loads. So, I have used collections...but its not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Define a class to hold your data, e.g.:

```
public class Dimension {

    private final int width ;
    private final int height ;

    public Product(
        @NamedArg("width") int width, 
        @NamedArg("height") int height) {
        this.width = width ;
        this.height = height ;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width ;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height ;
    }

    public int getArea() {
        return width * height ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d X %d", width, height);
    }
}
```

The `@NamedArg` annotation allows you to provide constructor arguments in the FXML file, so in your FXML you can do

```
<ComboBox fx:id="dimensionCombo" editable="true" promptText="Other" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="13" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
              <Dimension width="30" height="20" />
              <Dimension width="30" height="40" />
              <Dimension width="30" height="50" />
              <Dimension width="60" height="40" />

        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

And in your controller you can do

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<Dimension> dimensionCombo ;

// ...

int value = dimensionCombo.getValue().getArea();
```

If you want the combo box to be editable, you need to provide a `StringConverter<Dimension>`, to allow the combo box to create a new `Dimension` object from the value typed into the text field. In the controller, add

```
public void initialize() {
    dimensionCombo.setConverter(new StringConverter<Dimension>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Dimension d) {
            return d.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension fromString(String s) {
            String[] factors = s.split("[xX]");
            if (factors.length != 2) {
                return null ;
            }
            try {
                int w = Integer.parseInt(factors[0].trim());
                int h = Integer.parseInt(factors[1].trim());
                return new Dimension(w, h);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {   
                return null ;
            }
        }
    });

    // ...
}
```